# Adding subscriber to dotmailer address book

Tags: php, nusoap

I'm having issues adding a subscriber to a specific addressbook in dotmailer using nusoap. I've no problem adding a generic subscriber to all contacts using the [CreateContact](http://www.dotmailer.co.uk/api/contacts/create_contact.aspx) method however when I try and use the [AddContactToAddressbook](http://www.dotmailer.co.uk/api/address_books/add_contact_to_address_book.aspx) method, I just doesn't work.
The if statement used at the bottom returns successful, however nothing exists in the `$result` variable.

```
<?php
function subscribe($email, &$result)
{
    global $postURL, $username, $password;

    $addressBookId = "######";
    $contact = array("Email" => $email, "EmailType" => "Html");
    $params = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password, "contact" => $contact, "addressbookId" => $addressBookId);

    $client = new soapclient($postURL, true);
    $error = $client->getError();
    $result = $client->call('AddContactToAddressbook', $params);

    if($client->fault) {
        $rv = false;
    } else {
        // Check for errors
        if($error) {
            $rv = false;
        } else {
            $rv = true;
        }
    }
    return $rv;
}

if(subscribe("test@test.com", $result)) {
    echo "success<br />";
    print_r($result);
} else {
    echo "failed<br />";
}
?>
```

This code works as is with only changing

`$result = $client->call('AddContactToAddressbook', $params);`
to

`$result = $client->call('CreateContact', $params);`

But then the subscriber is not in any particular list. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong.

p.s. the `$addressBookId` variable has been blanked out intentionally, I didn't try to run it with '######' as the value in case you were wondering.
And once in production the `$result` variable will not be returned with the function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

`$result = $client->call('AddContactToAddressBook', $params);`

capital `B` on book

Comment: Heh, that'll teach me to copy and paste directly from dotmailers examples. I did think it was a little odd they had a lower case b in their example.

Thanks

Comment: Dotmailer's examples are extremely inaccurate (or out of date), i fought with their API for 3 weeks only a month ago. You'll learn quickly to double check all example code against google results and their API docs (bearing in mind even parts of their API doc's are no longer valid)

Comment: We've fixed the documentation for that individual method with correct casing. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Dotmailer has tons of inconsistencies, especially with naming, always check the case and never rely on the docs, use the WSDL and grab your data out of there, `getAddressBookContactCount` => `addressbookid`, `everything_else` => `addressBookId`, amongst mannnyyy others.. Better yet convince your manager to move to a more professionally built email manager.